# A Spring and two masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

Consider the system above such that mass $m1 $ is above mass $m2$ (their hieght is neglectable), a spring constant $k$ and $l,h$ as described. (apart of $m1, m2$ other masses are irrelevant).

Both mass are are free-falling until the spring is being attached when reaching the bottom, and is connected to $m2$.

**What is the velocity of m1 when disconnecting from m2 ?**

*Attempt -*

$E_0 = (m1+m2)gh$

$E_1 = (m1+m2)g(l-dX_{max}) + \frac 12kdX_{max}^2$

$E_{final} = \frac {m_{1}v_f^2}2 + \frac{m_{2}v_f^2}2$

The energy converstae due to conversative forces in the system.

I don't feel like my solution is right.. any thoughts ?

Comment: Why would it disconnect? There is *nothing* pushing $m_1$ away from $m_2$. Hint: Always start with a free body diagram.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: The spring can only push mass $m_1$ into mass $m_2$ and not separate them. There must be something missing here. Please edit the question and make it clear why you think otherwise.

Comment: The spring is attached to $m2$, $m1$ is above $m2$, therefore the spring will push both masses upward until  $m2$ will be pull back and $m1$ will continue upward, as far as my understanding goes..